# Repeating table caption after page break

Tags: html, css, printing, css-tables, caption

When printing an HTML table, you can use CSS to force the table's header row to display again after the page break. This style:

```
@media print {
   thead { display: table-header-group; }
}
```

Results in:

```
Caption
-------------
Col1  | Col2
-------------
Data1 | Data2
Data3 | Data4

--Page Break--

Col1  | Col2
-------------
Data5 | Data6
```

Is there a way to also repeat the table caption after the page break? I would think you could do something like `caption { display: table-caption-group; }`, but this doesn't exist. The solution would need to work in IE9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’m afraid there is no way to achieve that. In principle, you can set `caption { display: table-caption-group; }`, but by the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display), “If a table contains multiple elements with 'display: table-header-group', only the first is rendered as a header; the others are treated as if they had 'display: table-row-group'.” So you would not be able to make both the `thead` and the `caption` repeat. Besides, IE 9 does not get even let you repeat `caption` alone (Firefox does).

The workaround is to turn the `caption` element to a table row that is part of the `thead` element. E.g., for a two-column table:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th colspan=2>Caption
<tr><th>Header cell <th>Another header cell
</thead>
```

Comment: That's the conclusion I came to also. I had hoped I could do it more semantically, but I guess I should be happy that it's possible at all, considering the low support of CSS printing features.